# После удаление динамического элемента HTML блокируется взаимодействие со всей страницой

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка

В HTML динамически добавляется элемент, которы ложится поверх всего содержимого сайта. После закрытия этого элемента(окна) он удаляется из HTML, больше не отображается, но взаимодействовать с сайтом не получается, то есть ссылки, кнопки при наведении на них курсора меняют свои стили, но нажатия на них не обрабатываются.

```
userIcon.addEventListener('click', () => {
    burgerAnimate();
    document.body.innerHTML += authPanel;
    document.querySelector('.btn-close').addEventListener('click', () => {
        var element = document.querySelector('.auth-panel');
        element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
    });
    authWithGoogle();
});
```

Элемент с классом *'.btn-close'* является дочерним от *authPanel*

Comment: Перед удалением `display:none` задать и все?

Comment: @Leonid , это не помогает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.body.innerHTML += authPanel;
```

Эквивалентно по смыслу следующему коду:

```
let html = document.body.innerHTML;
html = html + authPanel;
document.body.innerHTML = ''; // Здесь все связанные с элементами события теряются
document.body.innerHTML = html; // Здесь добавляется новая разметка, которая преобразуется в DOM, CSS новое дерево благополучно принимает, а JS - нет!
```

То есть, body полностью меняет всё содержимое, а потому работает только событие, которое определяется после такой замены:

```
document.querySelector('.btn-close').addEventListener('click', () => {});
```

**Вывод:** лучше используйте `body.append()` или `body.insertAdjacentHTML()`